# Concrete 5 upgraded to 5.6.2.1

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete

After upgrade to 5.6.2.1 I am getting two issues when I enable the Full page cache (On-In all cases) in Dashboard -> System & Setting -> Cache & speed setting.

Issue #1 : Search Keyword Issue
The search uses the keyword of first entered text. If I login in the site, search for a keyword 'vision', it shows result. But If I again type for keyword 'light' it show only the results of first entered keyword 'vision'

Issue #2 : $_GET, $_REQUEST is not working
I have written custom module for a form, afer form submit i write header:location with query string. Redirection work properly but I could not get the query string values. I tried both $_GET and _REQUESt methods. It prints only the null values.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you review the Support Cases and FAQs on http://concrete5.org - there is a very lively discussion board.  I am not trying to push you away from here, but since the Concrete5 Team develops the software, they also provide support too.  There is a lot of the Dev Team frequents the Concrete site too.

For example with your issue with search - http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/chat/search-only-functions-if-one-word-is-entered#101927

GET_Request is talked about here - http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/requestget-in-tools/

Comment: I already submit a ticket in Concrete5 forum, yet did not get reply.
I already checked the link for GET_Request and now checked the link Search, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this **make a backup of the full site**!!!

After making your backup, **make a backup of your database**!!!

Do a clean install of 5.6.2.1, in other words, delete all files on the server. Then install concrete 5 again.

Upload all the files that you have changed for your custom pages and blocks etc. and your theme if you are using a custom theme.

Reload the backup of your database.

Whenever I get things that does not behave correctly this is what I do.